# UIAlertView delay or not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

I have used UIAlertView several times without problems but this time I can't make it work correctly.
The (simple) code is the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                      message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Reload data ?"]
                                     delegate:self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];    
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"executed");
}
```

If I touch in a row of the TableView I have two different behaviours:

1. the alertView is shown after some (6/7) seconds
2. the alertView is not shown. In this case, as soon as I touch in any
   point of the screen the alert is shown immediately.

In both cases, the [alert show] is executed immediately after the first touch because I see "executed" in the Log screen.
Before and after the alert, the application is not doing anything else.

Any help ?

Comment: I suggest running your project for Profiling (from the Xcode menus:  Product -> Profile), and choose the time profiler.  What's your CPU usage like when you're waiting on that alert?  Are you stuck in a function somewhere, blocking the main thread?  That would stop the alert from appearing (as well as make your entire app unresponsive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@""
                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Reload data ?"]
                                 delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];    
       [alert show];
       NSLog(@"executed");
    }];
```

Comment: Works great ! Could you explain why my code didn't work (I used it several times)?

Comment: I think with iOS 7 and 8 with swift support and the deprecated UIAlertView it does not work as before and the main thread block alert view.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not but `UIAlertView` is in fact deprecated in iOS8.

That being said, you can still use it. For future project targeting iOS8+ Apple recommends that you use `UIAlertViewController` instead.

This is an example of using [UIAlertViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) to open the application's settings:

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Go to settings" message:@"Do you wish to go to the application settings?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert]; ;
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
UIAlertAction *settingsAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}];
[alertController addAction:cancelAction];
[alertController addAction:settingsAction];

[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @skrilled Why do you believe this doesn't answer the question? In my opinion this answers the question by offering an alternative which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Please look at the extensive edit that was made to the post *after* I reviewed the answer posted. My comment was in regards to this comment in its original state and is an automated part of how StackOverflow works when answers and questions are reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and for me the problem was I had two queues running simultaneously. I had UI changes occurring in the main queue (all UI changes are required to occur in the main queue) and I had a very computationally intensive task occurring in a separate queue. My initial set up was:

```swift
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Custom message", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)

// perform time intensive task in seperate queue
```

To fix the issue, I moved the intensive task into the completion callback:

```swift
let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Custom message", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: {
    // perform intensive task here
})
```